# A limit with one or two numeric digits Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, digits

I am trying to figure out how to create a regex that will let me search for not only one or double digits, but also have a limit from 1-60. I want double digits to be applicable as well so for example, 01-09 works just as well as 1-9.

```
^([1,2,3,4,5]\d{0,1}|(60))
```

is what I have so far in terms of setting up the the double digits, but I then can't get 7, 8, 9 to pass as either single or double digits. Any idea on how to solve this problem or do I need to do a case by case approach?

Comment: `/^(60|[1-5][0-9]|0{0,1}[1-9])$/` Use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
^0*([1-9]$|^[1-5][0-9]$|^60$)
```

from [this generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/)

ie, can either be just 1-9, or 1-5 followed by 1-9, or 60 itself.

**Edit** amended to force begining and end of string and allows leading zeros

Comment: I edited my question as I want 01-09 to work alongside with 1-9. Also that command now accepts 61+ instead.